# How to calculate number of polygons that are formed by sequence of points in 2D?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

As you can see the example picture below, my question is how to determine the polygons that are formed by series of point.

1. On the left picture, the series of point is {A, B, C, D, E, A}, so it just forms 1 polygon {A, B, C, D, E}.
2. On the right side of the picture, the series of point is {A, B, C, D, E, F, A}. It creates 2 polygons {A, F, **G**} and {B, C, D, E, **G**}, where G is intersect point from line AB and FE.

I am not only interested in the number of polygons, but i also want to know the polygon information (polygon's series of points) that are created from it.

This algorithms will be used in mobile device, in real time, so it must be fast enough to compute. Oh, and the series of points will be generated by user's drag touch points.

Assumptions:

1. Only consists of 2 collinear points
2. It is not always closed chain polygonal. For example from picture on the right, the series of points is {A, B, C, D, E, F}, there is no edge FA.

I have been thinking the solution, and for looking the intersections points, I am stuck with the O(N^2) solution, N = number of edges. The optimization that I can do from this, is maintaining the sets of lines within some regions, so I just minimize the total lines that can be calculated each other.

As for the solution to extract what polygons are formed, I am still stuck.

[image: illustration]

Comment: You have the coordinates, right?

Comment: What are the assumptions? Is it always a closed polygonal chain?

Comment: No more than two collinear points?

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski: yes, i have the coordinates and it is always a closed polygonal chain

Comment: @VikramBhat: well, to simplify the problem, yes, no more than 2 collinear points

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski: i am sorry, I think it is not always a closed polygonal chain.

Comment: Check intersection of lines is the key.

Comment: Calculating all the intersections from a set of lines can be done in 'roughly speaking' n Log n time.  You should do an investigation of "plane sweep" algorithms; e.g. the Bentley-Ottmann algorithm.  I'd also recommend chapter 2 of "Computational Geometry" by Berg, Cheong, van Reveld and Overmars.

Comment: Seems to me that all you need to do is count the number of intersecting lines, add 1 to this number and that is the number of polygons. Or can you find a counter example?

Comment: Yes, the counter example is: one segment. No intersections, and answer is 0, not 1.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski It takes at least 3 points to create a polygon in the first place so a 2 point dataset shouldn't qualify for analysis. Other than zero, one and two point datasets, is there another configuration where intersections + 1 doesn't work?

Comment: Draw a square and wipe out one side: 4 points, no intersections, answer is 0 not 1.

Comment: @Agung Pratama : Did you find any proper solution for same?

Answer (score 2):

First, find all points where segments cross and create new segments ending there, so that no segments cross any more (except for their ends). Then think of it as a graph, and remove each vertex of degree 1 until all such are gone.

Mark all sides of all segments as not visited. For each not visited side `S` of segment `(A, B)` walk `A, B, C, ..., A` always taking the turn which is most on your `S` side (angle sort minimum or maximum). You just found a polygon. This will give you one additional polygon, which is "all the rest on plane".

Overall complexity O(n^2).

Comment: I don't think you can get a vertex of degree 1, since everything is connected to the vertex before and after (and `A` comes after the last vertex).

Comment: @Agung said it is not always a closed polygonal chain.

Comment: I think your solution would benefit from analysis of overall complexity - in particular showing the complexity for finding all the intersections.  Secondly, I think you may have an issue where two intersections are at exactly the same place.

Comment: Right, I'll edit the post with overall complexity. As to "same place" - I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: But the edge is drawn into the picture on the right.  I think he meant that the edge isn't necessarily given to us.

Comment: In the case of "same place" you might perhaps expand.  E.g. if you're creating a node with a higher degree, how are you then maintaining your "turn" information?  If you are representing it with multiple nodes, how are those nodes then connected?

Comment: If a node has degree > 2 I sort adjacent segment in order of angle and pick first if I want to turn left or last if I want to turn right.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which might help you : -

> 1. Find intersections between lines that are sides of polygons.
> 2. Make a directed graph containing interections and vertices with directed edges as sides of polygons
> 3. Do DFS and maintain another stack to put visited vertices. When visited vertex is revisited in DFS then pop the separate stack till
>      that vertex. The vertices popped are a vertices of a polygon. The
>      number times you encounter a visited vertex is the number of polygons
>      formed and popped vertices are in that order the sides of the
>      polygons.

**Time complexity : -**

```
1. Finding all intersections take O(NlogN) if efficient algorithms are used
2. O(N) for making graph out of intersections and vertices.
3. O(N) for DFS
```

**Total complexity:**- `O(NlogN)`

Comment: How is it possible to find all intersections in O(n log n) if the maximum number of possible intersetions is O(n^2)? (if every segment crosses every other except the two adjacent)

Comment: What is more, the graph size is not O(n), since it contains a vertex for each intersection. It is O(n^2) as well, and so is DFS time complexity for this graph.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski Sorry but i am talking about average case and i am not here prove here the worst case i am being optimistic and saying O(N^2) intersection is very rare. Please can you give of 16 interesects in four sided polygon for example ?

Comment: O(n^2) does not mean I can give you 16 intersections for 4 sides. The exact value of how many intersections are possible for n sides is (n-1)*(n-2)/2, which is 3 for n=4, but 4851 for n=100. The avarage case depends on what kind of data we are dealing with, which we do not know. Anyway, my point is that the "efficient algorithms" you mention do not exist (unless my calculation is wrong), and the complexity of your solution is O(n^2).

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski Search for Bentley-Ottmann if you dont know of O(nlogn) algorithms. And Kind of data we are dealing with are path and they mostly do not have that many intersection and from where did u get (n-1)*(n-2)/2 please can you explain because if have that many intersection i doubt you will have a connected path but just a collection of lines

Comment: Actually, the DFS part of your solution is wrong too. Consider two triangles ABC and ADE, ADE inside ABC. The polygons are ADE and ABCADE, you algorithm (the way I understand him) returns ADE and ABC.

Comment: how can ABCADE be a polygon it is divide in two polygons ABC and ADE so it gives correct ans ?

Comment: Quoting wikipedia "For an input consisting of n line segments with k crossings, the Bentley–Ottmann algorithm takes time O((n + k) log n)". With no additional assumptions, k is O(n^2), so Bentlry-Ottman algorithm gives O(n^2 log n). How did I get (n-1)*(n-2)/2? First and last can intersect anything except themselves and one adjacent. All other can intersect everything except themselves and two adjacents. That gives (2 * (n-2) + (n-2) * (n-3))/2. Idivide by two, because each intersections is counted twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45745/discussion-between-bartosz-marcinkowski-and-vikram-bhat)